# What explains the difference in distribution between these two snippets that choose items at random?

Tags: javascript, random

I just did a few tests to figure out some random item determination. Obviously, the first snippet here is the one to use if I ever needed a random item from the `items` array. But this question is not about that.

#### PickRandom.js

```js
const items = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ]
    , occurrences = {};

for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    const item = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
    if (!occurrences[item])
        occurrences[item] = 0;
    occurrences[item]++;
}
```

Running this resulted in an even distribution of occurrences between each element:

```js
{
  '0': 48093,
  '1': 47603,
  '2': 47631,
  '3': 47793,
  '4': 47621,
  '5': 47562,
  '6': 47679,
  '7': 47495,
  '8': 47868,
  '9': 47485,
  '10': 47626,
  '11': 47472,
  '12': 47524,
  '13': 47809,
  '14': 47713,
  '15': 47519,
  '16': 47582,
  '17': 47065,
  '18': 47729,
  '19': 47595,
  '20': 47536
}
```

#### RandomLoop.js

```js
const items = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ]
    , occurrences = {};

for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    for (const item of items)
    {
        const chance = Math.random();
        if (chance < 1 / items.length)
        {
            if (!occurrences[item])
                occurrences[item] = 0;
            occurrences[item]++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This snippet however didn't produce the same expected result, with a downward trend of occurrences per item:

```js
{
  '0': 47534,
  '1': 45530,
  '2': 42870,
  '3': 40932,
  '4': 39057,
  '5': 37186,
  '6': 35665,
  '7': 33784,
  '8': 31959,
  '9': 30593,
  '10': 28999,
  '11': 27644,
  '12': 26679,
  '13': 25524,
  '14': 24204,
  '15': 22974,
  '16': 21677,
  '17': 20646,
  '18': 19833,
  '19': 19018,
  '20': 18329
}
```

#### Question

I'm wondering why this is happening. Is there something wrong with the latter snippet? Also, the number of occurrences for the latter test doesn't seem to add up to the number of iterations I specified (`1,000,000`).

Comment: "*Also, the number of occurrences for the latter test doesn't seem to add up to the number of iterations I specified (100,000).*" `for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)` is one *million*, not one hundred thousand.

Comment: Yup, I meant to write `1,000,000`.

Comment: It doesn't add up because of the `if statement`. You, basically, have iterations where none of the occurrences happen. This is not the case in the first code

Answer (score 1):

1. Why distribution is not uniform:

Let's go through the second case. You have the same outer loop as in the first case that makes 1,000,000 iterations:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
   ...
}
```

Then, there is inner loop that iterates over `items`

```js
...
   for (const item of items)
   {
       ...
   }
...
```

First you pick the first `item` which is `0`. Then generate a random number (assume it was 0.001) and check `if (0.001 < 1/21)`. In this case it is `True` and therefore you update occurrences with

```js
occurrences[item]++;
```

and **exit the inner loop** with

```js
break
```

This what creates non uniform distribution: you always generate a `chance` for item `0` and if it was successfully generated you do not go to item `1`. Probability to update item `0` is 1/21, but the probability to update item `1` is a probability that a `chance` is below 1/21 given that a `chance` generated for item `0` was larger than 1/21 . This is conditional probability which is less than 1/21 . In general, you update `occurrences[item]` only if it was not updated for  all previous items. Therefore the probability to update item `0` is larger than the one for item `20`, and you get non uniform distribution as the result.

2. Why they do not sum up to 1,000,000:

This is because it is possible that random number generator will generate values larger than 1/21 for all items in the inner loop. In that case `occurrences` are not updated. As an example, assume that you got the following `chance` values for all items in the inner loop:

```js
[0.56, 0.98, 0.73, 0.12, 0.34, 0.22, 0.23, 0.07, 0.99, 0.26, 0.22, 0.78, 0.82, 0.09, 0.77, 0.08, 0.51, 0.66, 0.19, 0.68, 0.67]
```

All of them are larger than 1/21 ~ 0.048 , and the condition `if (chance < 1 / items.length)` is always `False`, so the outer loop will go to the next iteration without update of 'occurrences' array.

Answer (score 0):

What I discovered is that the iteration has a fundamental issue because there is a chance that none of the items are picked. To remedy this behaviour, we have to have a "chance pool", as I call it, for each item. This ensures that at least one item is picked, always.

```js
const items = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ]
    , occurrences = {};

for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
{
    const chance = Math.random();
    let pool = 0;
    for (const item of items)
    {
        if (chance < (pool += 1 / items.length))
        {
            if (!occurrences[item])
                occurrences[item] = 0;
            occurrences[item]++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

```js
{
  '0': 47504,
  '1': 47588,
  '2': 47603,
  '3': 47970,
  '4': 48023,
  '5': 47680,
  '6': 47408,
  '7': 47968,
  '8': 47824,
  '9': 47242,
  '10': 47736,
  '11': 47499,
  '12': 47892,
  '13': 47402,
  '14': 47307,
  '15': 47463,
  '16': 47792,
  '17': 47508,
  '18': 47599,
  '19': 47730,
  '20': 47262
}
```